# Determinant of the sum of rank-$1$ matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Let $A, B$ be a $n \times n$ diagonal matrices and $C = c c^T$ be also an $n \times n$ matrix. What is the determinant of $ACB + BCA$? Can we represent the determinant using $\det A$, $\det B$ and $\det C$?

Comment: Well, $det C$ is always zero as long as $n > 1$, so no reason to care about that one. :)

Comment: @Bemte Why $\det C$ is always zero? I think $C$ is a $n \times n$ symmetric matrix.

Comment: @PiggyJin $C$ is indeed a $n\times n$ symmetric matrix. It also happens to have rank $1$.

Comment: @Arnaud D. I got it. But, the determinant of sum of the two matrices whose determinants are zero may not be zero. Right?

Comment: Rodrigo's edit made me think of this question : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1637362/finding-null-space-of-symmetric-matrix-generated-by-outer-product/1637401 It's not exactly the same, but it could be helpful.

Answer (score 4):

$ACB+BCA$ is the sum of two rank-1 matrices. So, its rank is at most two and the determinant is always zero when $n\ge3$. When $n=2$, the matrix is given by $M=u v^T + v u^T = [u|v][v|u]^T$, where $u=Ac,\ v=Bc$ and $[u|v]$ denotes an augmented matrix. Hence
$$
\det M=\det([u|v][v|u]^T)=\det([v|u]^T[u|v])=(u^Tv)^2-(u^Tu)(v^Tv).
$$
This has very little to do with the determinants of $A,B$ and $C$.

Comment: It is a good news.!! Thank you.