# Maximum eigenvalue of $uv^T+(uv^T)^T$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> What is the maximum eigenvalue of  $\mathbf A$ where $\mathbf A =\mathbf{Q} + \mathbf{Q}^{T}$ and $\mathbf{Q} = uv^{T}$ ?

$u$ and $v$ are two unit vectors. I know the maximum eigenvalue of $\textbf{Q}$ is $u^{T}v$. However, I cannot deduce a relation of maximum eigen value of sum of two outer product matrices.

Is there any relation between Positive semidefinite matrices, max. eigen value and sum?

Comment: Related : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1637362/finding-the-null-space-of-symmetric-matrix-generated-by-outer-product

Answer (score 5):

We know that $A$ has rank at most equal to $2$.  Let $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$ denote the (possibly) non-zero eigenvalues of $A$.  These eigenvalues satisfy
$$
\begin{align*}
\lambda_1 + \lambda_2 &= \operatorname{tr}(A) = 2(u^Tv)\\
\lambda_1^2 + \lambda_2^2 &= \operatorname{tr}(A^2) = \operatorname{tr}((u^Tv)(uv^T + vu^T) + (v^Tv)uu^T + (u^Tu)vv^T)\\
&= 2[(u^Tv)^2 + (u^Tu)(v^Tv)]
\end{align*}
$$
We can solve these equations for $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$.

In particular, we note that
$$
\lambda_1 \lambda_2 = \frac 12 [(\lambda_1 + \lambda_2)^2 - (\lambda_1^2 + \lambda_2^2)] = (u^Tv)^2 - (u^Tu)(v^Tv)
$$
which means that the $\lambda_i$ are the two solutions to the quadratic equation
$$
\lambda^2 - [2(u^Tv)]\lambda + [(u^Tv)^2 - (u^Tu)(v^Tv)] = 0
$$
which means that the larger eigenvalue will be given by
$$
\lambda = (u^Tv) + \sqrt{(u^Tv)^2 - [(u^Tv)^2 - (u^Tu)(v^Tv)]} = 
u^Tv + \sqrt{u^Tu}\sqrt{v^Tv} = u^Tv + 1
$$

---

Another approach:

Write $v = au + bv_\perp$, where $u_\perp$ is a unit vector orthogonal to $u$.  Notably, $a = u^Tv$, and $a^2 + b^2 = 1$. We have
$$
A = uv^T + v^Tu = 
2auu^T + buu_\perp^T + bu_\perp u^T
$$
That is, if $U$ is the matrix whose columns are $u,u_\perp$, then we have $A = UMU^T$, where
$$
M = \pmatrix{2a&b\\b&0}
$$
Let $W$ be such that $[U \ W]$ is an orthogonal matrix.  We then have
$$
A = \pmatrix{U & W}\pmatrix{M & 0\\0 & 0} \pmatrix{U & W}^T
$$
That is, $A$ is similar to the block-diagonal matrix $\operatorname{diag}(M,0)$. Conclude that the eigenvalues of $M$ are the non-zero eigenvalues of $A$.

The characteristic polynomial of $M$ is the equation on $\lambda$ given above.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, $Q+Q^T$'s maximum eigenvalue is $\langle u,v\rangle + \lVert u\rVert\lVert v\rVert$. We can see this in another (perhaps geometric) way. Note that any symmetric matrix $A$ has maximum eigenvalue equal to
$$
\lambda_{\max}(A) = \max_{\lVert x\rVert = 1} x^TAx.
$$ In this case, we have $$x^T(Q + Q^T)x = x^T(uv^T+vu^T)x = 2\langle x,u\rangle\langle x,v\rangle$$ where $\langle a,b\rangle = a^Tb$ denotes the standard inner product. Suppose $u,v$ are unit vectors with $$\cos(\theta(u,v)) = \langle u,v\rangle$$ where $\theta(u,v)$ is an angle between $u$ and $v$. Assume $\theta(u,x) = \phi$. Then we have $\theta(v,x)\geq \theta(u,v)-\phi, $ and hence that
$$
2\langle x,u\rangle\langle x,v\rangle\leq 2\cos (\phi)\cdot\cos(\theta(u,v)-\phi) = \cos(\theta(u,v)) + \cos(\theta(u,v)-2\phi)\leq \langle u,v\rangle +1,
$$ where equality holds when $\phi = \frac{\theta(u,v)}{2}$. This proves the result. For the general case, let $u'=\frac{1}{\lVert u\rVert}u$ and $v'=\frac{1}{\lVert v\rVert}v$ to get $$\lVert u\rVert\lVert v\rVert(\langle u',v'\rangle+1)=\langle u,v\rangle + \lVert u\rVert\lVert v\rVert.$$